# What is the difference between the two ways of accessing the hdf5 group in SVHN dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, hdf5, h5py

I need to read the SVHN dataset and was trying to read the filename of the first image.

I am struggling a bit to understand the structure of HDF5 and especially in understanding the hierarchy/structure of the SVHN dataset

What is the difference between these two approaches of reading the name of the image?

I came across method 1 in this script inside the definition of `getName()` function: https://github.com/bdiesel/tensorflow-svhn/blob/master/digit_struct.py

I played around with the hdf5 format file and came up with method 2 while trying out different things that showed the same result.

```
# Both these methods read the first character of the name of the 1st
# image in svhn dataset
f = h5py.File(path_to_svhn_dataset,'r')

# method 1 
f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]].value

# method 2
f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()].value[0][0]
```

The first image is the file with filename "1.png". Both the above mentioned ways of getting the first character of the filename will give us int equivalent of ascii '1'-> 49

Comment: I understand you have SVHN image data in your HDF5 file, but the schema and dataset formats in the file are not clear to me. Can you share details? Then maybe I can help. Also, you can always open a HDF5 file with HDFViewer to "see" what's in there (the Group and Dataset hierarchy, along with the data).

Comment: I am struggling to understand the schema myself and failing to visualize it. I tried HDFViewer but that didn't work. The file is large but if this helps, it can be accessed here: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/

There is a kaggle kernel as well where the dataset is there: https://www.kaggle.com/stanfordu/street-view-house-numbers

I apologize for not being able to provide more content here.

Comment: I looked at those 2 locations yesterday, and didn't find any HDF5 (.h5) files. The first link has tar.gz and .mat files. The tar.gz files have png files and digitStruct.mat - no HDF5. Same at the kaggle site. Did you create your h5 file from another program?

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for checking. digitStruct.mat is actually encoded in HDF5 format. I used h5py to read the digitStruct.mat file. "path_to_svhn_dataset" in the code snippet I provided is the path to digitStruct.mat file. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Palo, I don't understand what you have. I don't think `digitStruct.mat` is a HDF5 file. I tried to open it with `h5py.File('digitStruct.mat','r')` function, and got a big traceback. `.mat` extension is typically a Matlab file (or a shortcut to a MS/Access Table).

Comment: I am not sure how to help here. :) I am able to open the digitStruct.mat using h5py.File using the exact same command (mine has the absolute path). My python version is 3.6.7. May I know what exception you are seeing? If this is not the right place to discuss please let me know that as well.

Comment: Palo, I made progress. I gave up on the files at standford.edu. I downloaded the files from kaggle.com and was able to open `test_digitStruct.mat`; `h5py.File()` works fine. Now that I can see the schema and data, I understand why there are so many questions about SVHN data. This is not a simple data model. The `/digitStruct/name` dataset contains object references that point to datasets in the `/#ref#/` group, and these datasets have object references to other datasets. It's complicated to unravel. I will write a complete answer that shows how these work and post later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a minor difference in output from your 2 methods.
Method 1: returns the full array (of the encoded file name)
Method 2: only returns the first element (character) of the array

Let's deconstruct your code to understand what you have.
The first part deals with `h5py` data objects.

`f['digitStruct']` -> returns a h5py **group** object
`f['digitStruct']['name']` -> returns a h5py **dataset** object
`f['digitStruct']['name'].name` -> returns the name (path) of the dataset object

Note:
The `/digitStruct/name` dataset contains "Object References". Each array entry is a pointer to another h5py object (in this case another dataset).
For example (spaces used to delineate the 2 object references):
`f[ f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0] ]` -> returns the object referenced at [0][0]
So, the outer `f[ obj_ref ]` works just like other object references.

In the case of `f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]`, this is an object pointing to dataset `/#refs#/b`
In other words, `f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]` references the same object as:
`f['#refs#']['b']` or `f['/#refs#/b']`

So much for h5py object references.
Let's continue to get the data from this object reference using **Method 1**.

`f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]].value` -> returns the entire `/#refs#/b` dataset as a NumPy array.

However, `dataset.value` is deprecated, and NumPy indexing is preferred, like this:
`f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]][:]`  (to get the entire array)

Note: both of these return the entire array of encoded characters.
At this point, getting the name is Python and NumPy fuctionality.
Use this to return the filename as a string:
`f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]][:].tostring().decode('ascii')`

Now let's deconstruct the object reference you used for **Method 2**.

`f['digitStruct']['name'].value` 
-> returns the entire `/digitStruct/name` dataset as a NumPy array.
It has 13,068 rows with object references

`f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0]` -> is the first row

`f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()` -> copies that array element to a python scalar

So all of these point to the same object:
Method 1: `f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]`
Method 2: `f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()`
And are both the same as `f['#refs#']['b']` or `f['/#refs#/b']` for this example.

Like Method 1, getting the string is Python and NumPy fuctionality.

`f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()][:].tostring().decode('ascii')`

Yes, object references are complicated....
My recommendation:
Extract NumPy arrays from objects using NumPy indexing instead of `.value` (as shown in Modified Method 1 above).

Example code for completeness. Intermediate print statements used to show what's going on.

```
import h5py

# Both of these methods read the name of the 1st
# image in svhn dataset
f = h5py.File('test_digitStruct.mat','r')
print (f['digitStruct'])
print (f['digitStruct']['name'])
print (f['digitStruct']['name'].name)

# method 1
print('\ntest method 1')
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]])
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]].name)
#  both of these get the entire array / filename:
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]].value)
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]][:]) # same as .value above
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'][0][0]][:].tostring().decode('ascii'))

# method 2
print('\ntest method 2')
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()]) 
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()].name) 

# this only gets the first array member / character:
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()].value[0][0])
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()].value[0][0].tostring().decode('ascii'))
#  this gets the entire array / filename:
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()][:])
print (f[f['digitStruct']['name'].value[0].item()][:].tostring().decode('ascii'))
```

Output from last 2 print statements for each method is identical:

```
[[ 49]
 [ 46]
 [112]
 [110]
 [103]]
1.png
```

Comment: Note, references to get an object in the dataset `f['digitStruct']['name']` use NumPy indexing. I copied the `[0][0]` index format used in the original post. You can also use `[0,0]` (which might be more intuitive). Also, since this is standard NumPy indexing, the first index points to the row in the dataset. You could use `[-1,0]` (or `[-1][0]`) to get the last row.