# Handling large scale dataset .mat file

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5

I have a large matfile MEG data  set (more than 2 GB) and I want to open that to figure out what is in it.

I have tried this

```
import h5py

with h5py.File('subject_1.mat', 'r') as file:

    print(list(file.keys()))
```

which gives

```
['#refs#', 'Data']
```

so I try

```
myvar = f['Data'].value
```

but then my kernel will shut down and crash.

I expect to see a time series but it is possibly too large for my computer.  Please note that my RAM is 16 GB.

Comment: Did you try loading the .MAT file in MATLAB? Also, are you sure that your .MAT file uses the HDF5 binary data format (.MAT version 7.3)?

Comment: Assuming your .mat file is a HDF5 file (version 7.3 or higher), you still have a challenge. The schema Matlab uses is not simple or easy (especially if you are new to HDF5). There are A LOT of object references. I wrote an Answer that explains how object references work for the SVHN data in .MAT/HDF5 format with Python/h5py. Take a look at this SO Q&A for insights:[the difference between the two ways of accessing the hdf5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643382/10462884). Also, it has links to some github projects that might help you.