# extracting data from HDF5 dataset

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a mat file I am reading with h5py, I need to extract the data en np.arrays or another form for analyzing it and plot it.

```
in: data   = h5py.File('footprints/HuascoFP.mat','r')

FP     = data["FP"]
FP.keys() # ---> ['EC', 'LAS', 'MWS', 'OMS', 'datenumber', 'meteo']
OMS    = FP["OMS"]
OMS.keys() #----> ['fp1D', 'fp2D', 'posR', 'posT']
fp2d   = OMS["fp2D"]#----> ['FP', 'x', 'y']
FP     =fp2d["FP"]
print(FP)

out:<HDF5 dataset "FP": shape (475, 1), type "|O">'
```

If I try "FP[:2]" I got : ([[],
       []], dtype=object) without any data.

Would like some help of you guys

Comment: What do you think of using pandas for both reading the h5 file and plotting?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you create this file by saving a MAT file using the 'save -v7.3' option to get HDF5 format? If so, get ready for some serious coding. Matlab uses "object references" to access the data. If you are new to HDF5 and h5py, these are not easy to work with (speaking from experience). You have to decode the `dtype=object` value to find the object it points to. Then you read THAT object. There are some examples in SO. (I wrote one that shows how to read the SVHN dataset in .MAT/HDF5 format.)

Comment: Thanks @kcw78, Do you have the example you mention? in fact, who gave the files save them in "v7.3". The output I print shows is actually: [<HDF5 object reference>] :(.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write as a comment, but it got too long.
Here is a link to my answer:
[SO_55566865:difference-between-two-ways-of-accessing-the-hdf5-group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643382/10462884)

It's long. The first part shows how to dereference HDF5 "Object References". (The rest of the answer is specific to the SVHN data set.)

I will try to apply to your example. (I think I got this right, but there may be errors since I can't test with your data.)
`data` in your code references a file object.
`FP = data["FP"]` references a top-level group called "FP", and so on.

Concatenating all your group and dataset names, your object reference is here: (I changed the name to avoid conflicts with the first value of 'FP')
`FP_arr = data["/FP/OMS/fp2D"]["FP"]`

**Method 1** in my example shows how to get the referenced object. What you do from there depends on the data you find.

`fp2d["FP"] or data["/FP/OMS/fp2D"]["FP"]` is an array of object references. Combine the object reference with the file object to get the next object. So, using your naming:
`obj_ref=fp2d["FP"][0][0]` is the first object reference.
`data[ fp2d["FP"][0][0] ]` or `data[obj_ref]` returns the first object.

You can print the path to this object with the `.name` attribute.
For the object above:
`obj_ref_name = data[obj_ref].name`
`print( obj_ref_name )`

You can see how this works by comparing 3 ways to access the referenced object. The following lines point to the same object, and should produce the same output:
`data[ fp2d["FP"][0][0] ]`
`data[obj_ref]`
`data[obj_ref_name]`

You can then use this to continue to interrogate the data.

Side note: Object references are hard. When I first stared working with them, I opened the HDF5 file with HDFView to "see" what was going on. It's a lot easier to understand that way.