# Read .mat file in Python

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, h5py

I know how to call any data from the attached file (URL) by Python except any data connected with the name "ROI". For example, you can check "data_dic_save/displacements/roi_ref_formatted". I want to use data from this path in my work (like mask and region). However, I cannot open (read) them. Could you help me?

URL for .mat file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/127vo3uew0fppw5/res.mat?dl=0

Code:

```
with h5py.File('~/res.mat', 'r') as f:
    d = f.get('data_dic_save/displacements/roi_ref_formatted')
    print(d.attrs['mask'])
```

Error message:

```
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (can't locate attribute: 'mask')"
```

Comment: This is a valid question. Your dataset (`data_dic_save/displacements/roi_ref_formatted`) doesn't have an attribute named `mask`. That's why you get the error. You can confirm this with `print (d.attrs.__contains__('mask'))` In fact, this dataset doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Dear kcw78, thank you for your reply. However, how can I read data from "roi_ref_formatted"? I checked this file in Matlab and got a lot of information from this path. But I need parse this file by Python...

Comment: Your dataset (`roi_ref_formatted`) is an array of object references with shape of (54,1). Use `print (d.dtype, d.shape)` to confirm. MATLAB saved as HDF5 is complicated. It uses object references that point to other objects in the file. To see how it works, `print (f[ d[0,0] ])` and you will get `HDF5 dataset "Lj"`, which is object reference that points to `f['/#refs#/Lj']` You can see this by comparing `print (f['/#refs#/Lj'][:])` to `print (f[ d[0,0] ][:])`

Comment: I checked your recommendations and got the following: 
object (54, 1)
<HDF5 dataset "Lj": shape (1, 6), type "<u4">
[[3707764736          2          1          1        110          1]]
[[3707764736          2          1          1        110          1]]
However, Matlab got another result (see attached link for screenshots). Why did I get these strange values???
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1uli6oeq9yzrn1r/AAAUI0qnymY1qoNRfok9J_Yva?dl=0

Comment: Warning: I am not an expert in MATLAB or Object References. Everything I know I learned by trail and error. I can't answer your "why" question. MATLAB uses a convoluted method to store data in HDF5 format (lots and lots of Object References). I opened your .mat file with **HDFVIEW**. All of the datasets in the `displacements` Group are 54X1 arrays of Object References. The same is true for all datasets in the `strains` Group. I suspect the datasets in the `dispinfo` and `straininfo` groups provide mapping. I found `region` and `size_mask` data in the `#refs#` datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is collected from my comments above, along with some additional insights regarding reading MATLAB files saved as HDF5. Frankly it's more complicated than a typical HDF5 file.

First, let's address your error reading the `mask` attribute. The dataset `data_dic_save/displacements/roi_ref_formatted` doesn't have an attribute named `mask`. That's why you get the error. You can confirm with:

```
print (d.attrs.__contains__('mask'))
```

In fact, this dataset doesn't have any attributes. The following code will iterate over all attributes of object `d`, then print the attribute names and values:

```
for name in d.attrs.__iter__():
    print (name, h5f.attrs[name])
```

Now, let's talk about MATLAB files in HDF5 format. (Caveat: I am not an expert in MATLAB or Object References. Everything I know I learned by trail and error).

I opened your .mat file with **HDFVIEW** from **The HDF Group**. I consider this an essential tool when starting with HDF5, as it let's you "see" the file's schema and data in a GUI. (Frankly it's the only way I can figure out the contents of a .mat file. They are NOT self-describing like most HDF5 files.) There is a snapshot of your file  at the end of this post for reference.

All of the datasets in the `displacements` Group are 54X1 arrays of Object References. The same is true for all datasets in the `strains` Group. I suspect the datasets in the `dispinfo` and `straininfo` Groups provide mapping of some kind. In addition, I found `region` and `size_mask` data in the `#refs#/XX` datasets.

You should read the h5py documentation for details about Object References.
Ref: [h5py Object Reference doc](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/refs.html#using-object-references)

Here's a brief explanation using your file.

The call below returns `d` as a NumPy array of shape `(54,1)` and dtype `object`. The print statement confirms same.

```
d = f.get('data_dic_save/displacements/roi_ref_formatted')
print (d.dtype, d.shape)
object (54, 1)
```

Object References point to other objects in the file. To see how it works, print the first array entry in `d`,and you will get a reference to dataset `Lj` (which will be in Group `/#refs#`). You can see the `Lj` dataset is a NumPy array of shape `(1,6)` and type `u4` (unsigned int).

```
print (f[ d[0,0] ]) 
<HDF5 dataset "Lj": shape (1, 6), type "<u4">
```

That means the following 2 statements point to the same object and yield the same result:

```
print (f['/#refs#/Lj'][:])
[[3707764736          2          1          1        110          1]]
print (f[  d[0,0] ][:])
[[3707764736          2          1          1        110          1]]
```

At this point, I am stuck interpreting the rest of your data. Here are some additional answers that might help you.

This SO Q&A gives a basic explanation on reading .mat files:
[read-matlab-v7-3-file-into-python-list-of-numpy-arrays-via-h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670480/10462884)

I wrote a more complete explanation (for reading SVHN datasets). You can access it here:
[what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-ways-of-accessing-the-hdf5-group-in-svhn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643382/10462884)

[image: HDFView of res.mat file]